# python lock method annotation

Tags: python, locking, annotations

Is there a python lock annotation which has the same effect to a python method as the "synchronized" keyword to java methods?

Comment: thanks for the comment, can you be more precise?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. Python has a "global interpreter lock", so only one thread can be executing Python code at a time, and you can't take advantage of multiple cores. But if your code is waiting for disk access, or data from the network, or numpy calculations, multithreading works.

Comment: Xavier, don't spout nonsense.  Multithreading is not always a bad idea.  Granted it has probs with its GIL on multi-core systems for some CPU bound code... but thats not enough to call the whole thing a "bad idea".

Comment: @Corey To quote guido Unfortunately, for most mortals, thread programming is just Too Hard to get right.... found in http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can assume that no builtin feature exist in python but you can implement it by understanding how it work in Java from [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_synchronized1.shtml) link :

> Every Java object created, including
>   every Class loaded, has an associated
>   lock or monitor. Putting code inside a
>   synchronized block makes the compiler
>   append instructions to acquire the
>   lock on the specified object before
>   executing the code, and release it
>   afterwards (either because the code
>   finishes normally or abnormally).
>   Between acquiring the lock and
>   releasing it, a thread is said to
>   "own" the lock. At the point of Thread
>   A wanting to acquire the lock, if
>   Thread B already owns the it, then
>   Thread A must wait for Thread B to
>   release it.

so maybe something like this can work :

synchronized statement in java:

```
public class Java {
    static private int count = 0;

    public void increment() {
       synchronized (this) {
          count++;
       }
    }
}
```

became :

```
import threading

class Java:
   cout = 0
   lock = threading.RLock()

   def increment():
       with Java.lock:
           Java.cout += 1
```

and synchronized method in Java:

```
public class Java {
    static private int count = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        count ++;
    }
}
```

became:

```
import threading

def synchronized(method):
    """ Work with instance method only !!! """

    def new_method(self, *arg, **kws):
        with self.lock:
            return method(self, *arg, **kws)


    return new_method

class Java:
    count = 0
    lock = threading.RLock()

    @synchronized
    def incremenet(self):
        Java.count += 1
```

Explicit is better than implicit.

N.B: my knowledge in Java is very limited, and it's my first lecture about this Java feature so maybe i miss something (or maybe i miss all the point here :) ), well hope this answer can help someone.

N.B: the lock that i have created is a class variable so threading synchronization happen in class level, if we want to make the synchronization in instance level (only) which i think that how java do it, the code above must change.

Comment: You can also use `with lock:` instead of the acquire and release methods.

Comment: You probably want to add a `return` into your decorator: it's not needed for your example but it lets you reuse the decorator with a method that returns something.  Also there's no particular reason to explicitly access the lock through the class so long as you don't assign to it you can access the class variable through the instance. `with self.lock: return method(self, *args, **kws)`

Comment: @Duncan: thanks for the remarks :) updated , now i'm angry about my self how did i miss that

Comment: I think the synchronized decorator should create the lock itself and store it decorated function. The the decorator is fully separated from the class, plus you can also use it on functions.

Comment: @THC4k: Sorry but i didn't understand quite what you mean, what i think you meant is that the lock should be bound to the decorator but the idea here is to have one lock shared by all the class method, like this only one method can acquire this lock. If i didn't understand well your comment can you repeat please , thanks :)

Comment: @singularity: The decorator decorates `Java.increment` which is a function that is shared between all instances. If you do `lock = threading.RLock()` in the decorator and `with lock:` in the wrapper that lock works on the class level too.

Comment: @THC4k : ok i think i know what you mean now, but it's not just about Locking access to the same method between different instance, we want also to synchronize the call of different method, like let's say we have two method __increment(self)__ and __decrement(self)__ having a lock in the way that you said wont guaranty to us exclusive mutation between the call of the two method because each one has her own lock , i hope i did answer you :)

Comment: @singularity: Yeah you're right. Guess there are too many possibilities.

Comment: With the lock declared at the class level all instances will synchronize against the same lock, which is not what happens in Java.

Comment: @mouad So if `self.lock` was set in the constructor instead, that would result in an instance-level lock (as in your second note), right?

Comment: Yes exactly you will end up with a different lock for each instance that you create.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use a decorator like this:

```
def synchronized(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            _ = self._lock
        except AttributeError:
            self._lock = threading.Lock()

        with self._lock:
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This solution has a race condition when calling the decorated method for the first time, though. The simplest way to avoid this problem is to call one synchronized method when no other threads are running first, or to assign the `self._lock` manually in `__init__`